# @csrf and @error directives in laravel 6 is not working

Tags: php, laravel

i am using laravel 6 and facing a problem when I use @error directive

[image]

I have cleared the cache of views and application but still didn't find anything helpful

my view code is

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('client.reset.password')}}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">E-Mail Address</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                                    @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Send Password Reset Link
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

my controller code is following

```
public `function` password()
{
    $messages = \Session::get('messages');

    return view('Client.ResetPassword')->with('message', $messages);
}
```

I have also cleared browser cache and also executed following commands

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view: clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

my HTML code from view source file

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Reset Password</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    
   

                     <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/WET-forntEnd/resetPassword">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">E-Mail Address</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                                    @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong></strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Send Password Reset Link
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: What is your view file named? It most likely is no `.blade.php` file

Comment: thanks for reply my view file name is ResetPassword.blade.php

Comment: Can you include the HTML from view source?

Comment: Can you double-check the name of the file, no whitespace or anything (maybe rename again)? This mostly happens when the file is not recognized as a Blade file and thus not parsed via Blade

Comment: i have renamed  multiple times but still getting this error

Comment: Very strange. How do you serve your files? What is the route you're using? Does this happen with other views or just this one? Do you have debugging turned on? Can you post the complete blade file, does it extend any layout file? (Please post this too)

Comment: in all views in which i am using @error directive but if i use if ($error->has('email')) then it works fine my laravel version is six and php version is ^7.4 bro i cant paste fullpage since it is saas product and i am not allowed to do this . Plz suggest me what should i do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.